# Cannot refresh page with header location

Tags: php, header, webserver, refresh, xampp

I'm using this code to do some stuff, but at the end it needs to redirect/refresh on my local xampp server PHP Version 5.4.4. Everything is working fine on my local server, but on the web it is running on PHP Version 5.3.14 and it does not redirect/refresh.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    # Variables->

    $rand = rand(10, 457);
    $folder_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['name']);
    $folder_name = strtolower($folder_name);
    $folder_name = "{$folder_name}{$rand}";
    if (!mkdir("albums/$folder_name", 0777, true)) {
        die('Failed to create folders...');
    } else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO albums (name,folder) VALUES (:name,:folder)";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'], ':folder' => $folder_name));
        header("Location: index.php?p=adm&a=adm-gallery");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens on version 5.3.14? Enable E_ALL error messages level and let us see the output.

Comment: Is you database query successful?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `header()` call.  The problem is elsewhere.  You probably are having an error with PDO.  Also, don't use relative paths for `Location:` headers!  You must use a full URL.  Most browsers do work with relative location headers, but there is no guarantee, and they are not allowed by the RFC spec for HTTP.

Comment: Query is successful. PDO is defined in some code above

Comment: Here is the E_ALL error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/garantt/domains/garant-totaal.nl/public_html/livedemo/index.php:4) in /home/garantt/domains/garant-totaal.nl/public_html/livedemo/adm/adm-gallery.php on line 38

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably have some output before header

use javascript

```
echo '<script> document.location = "index.php?p=adm&a=adm-gallery" ; </script>';
```

Comment: Your solution works .. but i dont understand why on mu local server is all fine and on the web its not!

Comment: your going to see a lot of this with header and sessions , the thing is the servers are very restrict about having output before these but for some reasons virtual servers like wamp and xamp doesn't care about them . and the result is you get your code working in the local but the same code doesn't work on the server . if youe sure you don't have a output on this page before header then it's most likely a empty space before or after closing your php tag in the page or in the included pages .